# How can I restrict predictive text to words in the current language?

Tags: iphone, keyboard, language, dictionary

I have Apple's QuickType keyboards for English and German installed on my iPhone. I get predictive text in both languages, but sometimes I'll get suggestions for German words when using the English keyboard and vice versa. Is there some way I can configure the phone so that when using the English keyboard, I get suggestions only for either (1) words in an English dictionary or (2) words I've added to my custom dictionary when using the English keyboard? Similarly, when using the German keyboard, I want suggestions only for either (1) words in a German dictionary or (2) words I've added to my custom dictionary when using the German keyboard.

I'm running iOS 11.2.2 on an iPhone 6.

Comment: what about words that stem from latin and have the same basic beginning?

Comment: It's purely a matter of which dictionaries the suggestions are pulled from. When using an English keyboard, pull only from English dictionairies (including words learned from me from my past use of an English keyboard). Ditto for German.